# How to access $nuxt in ssr / redirect in SSR

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I wrote the axios helper function to handle the error and authentication. I need to redirect to custom error page with custom message when error occurred

I use `$nuxt.error({message})` to do this function.

Helper

```
import axios from 'axios'
const myAxios = axios.create({
  headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }
})

myAxios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  return response
}, (error) => {

  const { response } = error
  const { status, statusText } = response
  if (process.client) {
    $nuxt.error({ message: statusText, statusCode: status })
  } else {
    console.log(this,$nuxt,$vm,app,context ....) // all undefined
  }
  return Promise.reject(error)
})

export default myAxios
```

Code

```
import myAxios from 'PATH/TO/THIS/HELPER'
..
...
..

myAxios.get('http://example.com')
```

It work perfectly. on client side only, when I refresh and run it on server side, it will return `$nuxt is not defined`

How to access nuxt in SSR?

Comment: The easiest solution is to use nuxt/axios and add _.vue in pages directory, and it will show it if something went wrong

Comment: @FadiQuader I created the _.vue but it still redirect to default NuxtServerError page